# Make command line compiler work with Xcode 4.3

Tags: command-line, xcode4, makefile

I have Xcode 4.3 and it works fine. However, running `make` to compile a program from the command line gives me many errors about missing standard headers, such as

```
error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
```

The problem may be that Xcode 4.3 (as opposed to older versions) is installed like a standard Mac app bundle (no installer inside a dmg..) so the paths don't get set up automatically.

How can I setup the command line tools to look into the /Applications/Xcode.app/ bundle and its subfolders for the standard headers and libraries?

```
$ which make
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using Xcode's make, not some make installed by MacPorts?  I've never had trouble typing `make` from the command line, but my only Mac project is https://github.com/GPGTools/GPGServices, which I didn't start myself, but maybe it'll give you some ideas.

Comment: edit your question to include some of the error messages, and the lines from your make file for \*INCL\* variables. Good luck.

Comment: @JeffBurdges - yes I'm sure. I have uninstalled MacPorts completely.

Comment: I'm using macports, maybe it sets this up, but I doubt it though.  `which make` should say `/usr/bin/make`

Comment: @JeffBurdges nope, see edited question. I'm thinking about just creating a bunch of symlinks into the app bundle..

Comment: Given the error message (stdio.h is about as basic as you can get ;-),  either your `[Mm]akefile` has no information about where to find it's INCLUDEs, or more likely, it has the wrong path listed. I don't use xCode, so that's as much as I can help. Good luck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the full release of XCode 4.3 (and OS X 10.7.3) you can go to Preferences > Downloads > Command Line Tools and click 'Install'.

It appears that you need to have a developer account though.